# How to set a record's field from the List in component to event?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, aura-iteration

I have a cmp with List of objects and iteration:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Objects}" var="object">
    <div label="Set Id" name="{!object.Id}" onclick="{!c.action}">
        {!object.Name}
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

Now by clicking "Set Id" I need to set the Id of that concrete object to my event. Now I set and get `[event.getSource is not a function]`:

```
var cmpEvt = component.getEvent("cmpEvt");
var objId =  event.getSource().get("v.name");
cmpEvt.setParams({"id" : "object.Id"});
cmpEvt.fire();
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cmp**

```
 <div label="Set Id" data-record="{!object.Id}" onclick="{!c.action}">
    {!object.Name}
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
  action : function(cmp,evt){
   var objId =  evt.currentTarget.dataset.record;
    var cmpEvt = cmp.getEvent("cmpEvt");
    cmpEvt.setParams({"id" : objId });
    cmpEvt.fire();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But... Hmm. `[event.getSource is not a function]` Can it be because of list and iteration?

Comment: can you updated your question with actual error code? so that it's easy to reproduce the issue

Comment: Please upvote if solution works for you for help others

Comment: Sorry for the misinformation. I recently changed the button to `div`. Everything works with the button, but not with `div`.

Comment: for `div` you have to use `datasets` , edited my answer  based on your comments.

Comment: Thank you :) Now it works.